# Parsing XML to Python object similar to suds

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Sorry if this is duplicate but I tried digging the Internet and did not really find something relevant.

I have been using suds and it is fantastic in the sense that it parses the results into objects (besides the element tree).

Now, I have a file that is pretty similar to a SOAP response (sans the envelop, etc.) and I am wondering if there is an easy way to parse it to a suds like object. The tags come with their ns. Here is a sample TAG, parsed and prettified with `ElementTree`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ns0:substation objectID="{16A743D9-AAA3-4187-94BF-77F63E25E5A6}" verb="New" xmlns:ns0="http://www.multispeak.org/Version_3.0">
  <ns0:extensions>
    <ns0:symbolCoord>
      <ns0:X>332.50187386</ns0:X>
      <ns0:Y>343.8680783</ns0:Y>
    </ns0:symbolCoord>
  </ns0:extensions>
  <ns0:mapLocation>
    <ns0:coord>
      <ns0:X>111.50187386</ns0:X>
      <ns0:Y>11.8680783</ns0:Y>
    </ns0:coord>
  </ns0:mapLocation>
  <ns0:facilityID>07xx</ns0:facilityID>
  <ns0:sectionID>07xx</ns0:sectionID>
  <ns0:parentSectionID name="ROOT" noun="substation" objectID="{00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"/>
  <ns0:phaseCode>ABC</ns0:phaseCode>
  <ns0:zMin>xx</ns0:zMin>
  <ns0:zMax>xx</ns0:zMax>
  <ns0:units>Ohms</ns0:units>
  <ns0:posSeqZ r="8.60217666625977" x="32.0800704956055"/>
  <ns0:zeroSeqZ r="11.5711364746094" x="44.1044578552246"/>
  <ns0:negSeqZ r="8.60217666625977" x="32.0800704956055"/>
  <ns0:busVolts>1.03332996368408</ns0:busVolts>
  <ns0:ohGndZ>40</ns0:ohGndZ>
  <ns0:ugGndZ>10</ns0:ugGndZ>
  <ns0:nomVolts>69.0001009674624</ns0:nomVolts>
  <ns0:ldAolloc>false</ns0:ldAolloc>
  <ns0:ldCon>D</ns0:ldCon>
  <ns0:isRegulated>false</ns0:isRegulated>
  <ns0:feederList/>
  <ns0:name>07xx</ns0:name>
</ns0:substation>
```

Aside: Is there a better way to replace the ns0 url for all tags than regex/string replacement on the original xml?

Update: Here is the (trimmed) content of file:

```
<MultiSpeakMsgHeader Version="3.0" AppName="XXX" AppVersion="8.1.3.2741.988695b6" Company="XX" xmlns="http://www.multispeak.org/Version_3.0" SessionID="1" PreviousSessionID="1" ObjectsRemaining="0">
    <MultiSpeak documentType="dump" connectivityModel="Sectional">
        <substation objectID="{16A743D9-AAA3-4187-94BF-77F63E25E5A6}" verb="New">
            <extensions>
                <symbolCoord>
                    <X>0.50187386</X><Y>0.8680783</Y>
                </symbolCoord>
            </extensions>
            <mapLocation>
                <coord>
                    <X>0.50187386</X><Y>0.8680783</Y>
                </coord>
            </mapLocation>
            <facilityID>07xx</facilityID>
            <sectionID>07xx</sectionID>
            <parentSectionID name="ROOT" noun="substation" objectID="{00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"/>
            <phaseCode>ABC</phaseCode>
            <zMin>X0X</zMin>
            <zMax>X0X</zMax>
            <units>Ohms</units>
            <posSeqZ r="8.60217666625977" x="32.0800704956055"/>
            <zeroSeqZ r="11.5711364746094" x="44.1044578552246"/>
            <negSeqZ r="8.60217666625977" x="32.0800704956055"/>
            <busVolts>1.03332996368408</busVolts>
            <ohGndZ>40</ohGndZ>
            <ugGndZ>10</ugGndZ>
            <nomVolts>69.0001009674624</nomVolts>
            <ldAolloc>false</ldAolloc>
            <ldCon>D</ldCon>
            <isRegulated>false</isRegulated>
            <feederList/>
            <name>07xx (X0X)</name>
        </substation>
        <transformerBank objectID="{15EF1495-4D7B-4A30-A6D5-1B5CB2314A78}" verb="New">
            <extensions>
                <symbolCoord>
                    <X>0.86176248</X><Y>0.7434433</Y>
                </symbolCoord>
            </extensions>
            <mapLocation>
                <coord>
                    <X>0.50187386</X><Y>0.8680783</Y>
                </coord>
            </mapLocation>
            <facilityID>MXFMR070</facilityID>
            <sectionID>MXFMR070</sectionID>
            <parentSectionID name="07xx (X0X)" noun="substation" objectID="{16A743D9-AAA3-4187-94BF-77F63E25E5A6}"/>
            <phaseCode>ABC</phaseCode>
            <wdgCode>D-Y</wdgCode>
            <vInput>67.0000535137532</vInput>
            <vOut>7.19999980926514</vOut>
            <tertVolts>0</tertVolts>
            <tertChild name="MXFMR070" noun="transformerBank" objectID="{15EF1495-4D7B-4A30-A6D5-1B5CB2314A78}"/>
            <vOutNom>7.19999980926514</vOutNom>
            <vOutNomTertiary>0</vOutNomTertiary>
            <transformerList>
                <transformer objectID="{15EF1495-4D7B-4A30-A6D5-1B5CB2314A78}-ABC">
                    <kva>4750</kva>
                    <phases>3</phases>
                    <phase>ABC</phase>
                    <impedance>10.7299995422363</impedance>
                    <nLLoss>0</nLLoss>
                    <eaEquipment>519-X0X070</eaEquipment>
                </transformer>
            </transformerList>
        </transformerBank>
        <ohPrimaryLine objectID="{21EC1A14-276F-48EB-8955-80C0EF921CEB}" verb="New">
            <extensions>
                <note>LINE IS NOT HOT, JUMPERS CUT,  NO FUSES ON POLE</note>
            </extensions>
            <complexLine>
                <coord>
                    <X>0.37190654</X><Y>0.9178412</Y>
                </coord>
                <coord>
                    <X>0.78998409</X><Y>0.5761478</Y>
                </coord>
            </complexLine>
            <sectionID>OH19244</sectionID>
            <parentSectionID name="ROOT" noun="substation" objectID="{00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"/>
            <phaseCode>A</phaseCode>
            <conductorList>
                <conductor>
                    <conductorType>#4 ACSR 6/1</conductorType>
                    <phase>A</phase>
                </conductor>
            </conductorList>
            <condN>#4 ACSR 6/1</condN>
            <condLength>415.600311279297</condLength>
            <constr>SystemCnstDefault</constr>
            <operVolt>7.19999980926514</operVolt>
        </ohPrimaryLine>
        <ohPrimaryLine objectID="{69B06530-99C3-4056-8929-D6E5583911AE}" verb="New">
            <complexLine>
                <coord>
                    <X>0.78998409</X><Y>0.5761478</Y>
                </coord>
                <coord>
                    <X>0.00206882</X><Y>0.0113029</Y>
                </coord>
            </complexLine>
            <sectionID>OH19245</sectionID>
            <parentSectionID name="OH19244" noun="ohPrimaryLine" objectID="{21EC1A14-276F-48EB-8955-80C0EF921CEB}"/>
            <phaseCode>A</phaseCode>
            <conductorList>
                <conductor>
                    <conductorType>#4 ACSR 6/1</conductorType>
                    <phase>A</phase>
                </conductor>
            </conductorList>
            <condN>#4 ACSR 6/1</condN>
            <condLength>422.347900390625</condLength>
            <constr>SystemCnstDefault</constr>
            <operVolt>7.19999980926514</operVolt>
        </ohPrimaryLine>
    </MultiSpeak>
</MultiSpeakMsgHeader>
```

Comment: SO is note a code writing service, if you want to get a proper answer you need to update your question with the code that your have tried so far.

Comment: "a better way" can only be compared if you provide your "way" to begin with. But in general I do not think using regex/string replacement is a good idea, use a proper xml parser.

Comment: @Anzel My way was to simply text replace `xmlns:ns0="http://www.multispeak.org/Version_3.0"` with `xmlns:ns0="new_url"` and I mentioned I do not find it a good idea. I already mentioned I am using `ElementTree`, I am not sure if it offers a clean way to replace all the name space attribs.

Comment: `ElementTree` from which module/library? Are you using standard library `xml` or you have `lxml`?

Comment: @Kasramvd the original XML is huge and is not prettified. I will try to find a way to shorten it and post it as well.

Comment: @Anzel `xml.etree.ElementTree`

Comment: then check out `fixtag`, it could be what you're after. Alternatively, you can iterateparse with event hooks, and check/change from there.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to use 'lxml.objectify':

```
from lxml import objectify
o= objectify.fromstring(xml)
```

ref: http://lxml.de/objectify.html#element-access-through-object-attributes